# 'No tests were found' when trying to run rspec on Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd, rubymine

I'm trying to do a Ruby Kada, but when I try to run my spec, I get "No tests were found."

I have 2 files in my project:

`poker_hands.rb`, which contains:

```
def announce_winner (s)
   'Player x is the winner.'
end
```

and `poker_hands_spec.rb`, which contains:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'poker_hands'

define 'poker_hands' do
   it 'should announce a winner' do
      x = announce_winner('')
      x.should == 'Player x is the winner.'
   end
end
```

I'm running RubyMine 4.0.3 and rspec 2.10.0

edit: [**Here is a copy of my stacktrace**](http://pastebin.com/4ZNhvfMQ)

Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with the answer below.  I use rubymine and rspec as well and have no problems.  Rubymine is outstanding isn't it?  "describe" is what signals the start of a spec test.

Comment: It's called a Kata, not Kada btw.

Answer (score 3):

The rspec keyword to define a context is **`describe`**, and not `define`.